# What would happen if I fire a gun in an environment with hyper-gravity?

Tags: physics, astrophysics, firearms, guns, modified-gravity

So I've seen a lot of research done into how guns react in low gravity environments as well as on space stations. However, for my story I was wondering how the trajectory, force and speed of the bullet would be impacted. The planet has a thin atmosphere but a gravity that exceeds earth's. I think that firing a gun in low gravity results in the bullet moving faster, but I'm not sure. Would this mean that firing a gun in hyper-gravity results in the bullet moving slower towards its target? And if so, would this result in the bullet falling back to the planet's surface because of the gravitational pull, before reaching its target.

Comment: gravity does not change the speed of the bullet just how far it goes, air pressure controls the speed.

Comment: "firing a gun in low gravity results in the bullet moving faster" -- If there's any such effect, it would be so small for a typical firearm that you'd have trouble measuring it.

Comment: I think it's density (vs pressure) that has the biggest effect on drag, which is what slows the bullet down.

Comment: We probably need a rough definition of what level of gravity we are talking about - 2x Earth? 10x ? Greater still?

Comment: Higher gravity would reduce the distance the bullet traveled before it hitting the ground. It would not affect its velocity, atmospheric density being the same. Season corner-cases to taste. (yes ihere would be more friction in the barrel and thus be slowed... this isn't really what the OP is looking for IMO...)

Comment: @TonyEnnis meaning that any type of indirect fire artillery will have troubles, including rockets. "Operation Gravity" actually touched the topic - on an elliptic planet inhabitants of low-gravity area had a form of catapult artillery and crossbows , I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLDR: depending on how extreme the changes are to gravity/atmosphere, gun development would completely change and they would act more like modern artillery (on a much smaller scale) than anything we think of today.

Extremely thin atmosphere along with super high gravity basically means your gun would be used more like a small mortar launcher than anything resembling how guns are used on earth.  Gravity still affects bullets on earth but for most usages it makes very little difference. This is because most gun battles are going to be close range, so gravity simply doesn't have much time to change the direction by much.  The exceptions are going to be long range rifle shots, and snipers certainly take the effects of it into account.

The atmosphere also heavily affects how guns are used and ammo is developed.  The atmosphere has two main effects -- it significantly limits range for most guns/ammo types because the bullet quickly loses velocity which causes it to tumble.  For long range guns it plays a major role through rifling, where the bullet is aerodynamically stabilized by being spun.  Thus, by removing the atmosphere you would greatly change the development of firearms.  The design of the bullets would probably change significantly because aerodynamics are much less important, and traditional things like rifling would be completely pointless.

To sum it up, guns would be very different in a world with much less atmosphere and much higher gravity.  Even short range gunfights would be unrecognizable if you pump the gravity high enough as you'd basically be firing at 35-70 degree angles (to the horizon) into the sky and people would be arcing the bullets over the enemies cover.  One would assume guns would become computers generating firing and aiming solutions much like modern artillery because traditional aiming would be near impossible.  I wouldn't be surprised if bullets completely changed into cylindrical explosive balls.

But as a caveat it really depends a lot on how extreme you make things.  If it's just 2x gravity and 1/2 atmosphere that's a lot different than 10x with 1% atmosphere.

Comment: *" If it's just 2x gravity and 1/2 atmosphere that's a lot different than 10x with 1% atmosphere."* That's rather the opposite of what you'd expect. Gravity exerts a downward force on air molecules, and the lower altitude molecules exert an upwards force counteracting that. In general, the more gravity, the more air density (that's why air density is higher at low altitudes and on Jupiter).

Answer (score 29):

Gravity doesn't affect the velocity at which the bullet leaves the gun, that is a function of the energy released by the gunpowder.

Gravity affects only how fast the bullet will reach the ground while it is moving after the explosion of the gunpowder or, in other words, the vertical component of the velocity vector.

This results, all the rest being the same, into a bullet going further away into lower gravity and the opposite in higher gravity.

Example:

- planet A has low gravity, reaching the ground from 2 meters height takes 4 second.
- planet B has high gravity, reaching the ground from 2 meters takes 0.5 seconds.

When firing horizontally from 2 meters height a bullet with muzzle velocity 500 m/s, on planet A it will travel 2000 m before hitting the ground, while on planet B it will just travel 250 meters (ignoring drag).

Comment: I think the air is thicker in hyper gravity️

Comment: @user6760 the OP has specified that the planet has a thin atmosphere.  It might be expected that a high gravity planet would normally have a more dense atmosphere, but not in this situation.

Comment: There might be additional questions about friction inside the barrel of the gun if the gravity is strong enough to pull the bullet down and "grind it against the metal", adding friction terms and potentially wearing the gun down sooner. But mostly yeah, bullets (like everything else) fall down faster.

Comment: The thin atmosphere would be measured as thin in depth, not in density!

Comment: "*gravity doesn't affect the velocity at which the bullet leaves the gun*" only if you aim perfectly horizontally.

Comment: @DKNguyen for a bullet velocity of 200 m/s and a barrel length of 0.1 m,  a gravity of 100 m/s2 would eat  just 1% of the kinetic energy of the bullet while it moves in the gun.

Comment: @BarbaudJulien there is already a LOT of friction inside the barrel, the bullet gets squeezed through it with enough force that the metal jacket deforms to fit into the rifling and also creates a seal for the propellant (ignited gunpowder) behind it. Increased gravity would have a negligible impact (unless it's increased by many orders of magnitude, to the point where having a straight barrel supported at one end would become problematic).

Answer (score 7):

I was going to put this in a comment to @l.dutch - but it kinda morphed into an Answer.

The issue is that when one has a Firearm, one has to sight it in. For reference - All of my rifles (except my .22s) are sighted in for 100m.

This means at 0 metres (for my .308) the offset between where I aim and where the bullet hits is 1.5 inches, due to the Ballistic arc.

And that is where our Super Gravity is going to have an impact(heh) - Higher Gravity means I'm going to have to sight my Rifle in more aggressively (to account for the changed ballistic arc) and whilst I CBF doing the Maths - depending on the round chosen and the ballistics - you could end up with a projectile that resembles more an Mortar shell trajectory.

e.g. something slow and subsonic like .45 ACP

**And this would absolutely have an impact on Bullet Speed, especially as it slows downs approaching the top of it's ballistic arc and as it speeds up come down on it's ballistic arc**

Unfortunately, all the online/free Ballistic Calculators have Gravity as a fixed constant. There are some super long range ones that are very expensive that do factor in changes in earths Gravity (I think, I don't do that sort of long-range shooting)

In short - Yes, it will have some impact, because of Ballistic Arcs and that firearms are Zero'd for a specific range.

Comment: What L. Dutch said is that "gravity doesn't affect the velocity at which the bullet **leaves the gun**", but changes how far it goes after that by changing the vertical component of the velocity vector. It's basically the same thing you said, but with different terms.

Comment: @Mermaker - Kinda, but not. Consider this - if a .45 ACP round (subsonic) is hitting the top of it's ballistic arc at around 50 yards, depending on angle of fire etc. etc. it could have a velocity *at that point* slower, to the point where it's a significant factor, potentially being slow enough to be non-Lethal. Terminal Ballistics is the issue here and although one sights in a Firearm at a known distance - engagements aren't always at the same distance - and this difference in an extreme gravity situation could impact the terminal effects.

Answer (score 4):

As a thought experiment, replace guns and bullets with slingshots and angry birds. You can assume the birds are spherical for this exercise. You will be better able to picture what happens in different gravities.

[image: A screenshot of Angry Birds with some equations used by the game]

You can find a great deal of nerding and mathing in one of our more science-oriented sister stacks: [How does gravity affect bullets? @Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10773/31264).

But in short: the gun/slingshot imposes a force on the projectile, which causes it to be accelerated to a certain velocity. That velocity is the sum (vectorial addition) of a horizontal speed and a vertical speed, at the point in which the projectile leaves the weapon. As the projectile flies, gravity keeps changing the vertical speed over time. The more intense gravity is, the quicker the trajectory bends downwards. Notice that in a vacuum, the horizontal component of the projectile's velocity is constant.

Comment: I looked at this and immediately heard the Theme song in my head. Good times.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends.

You say your planet has a higher gravity and a thinner atmosphere than Earth meaning the bullet will be pulled to the ground faster but there would be less friction giving it further distance. I'm assuming the explosive reaction when firing it is no different to any other gun/bullet you'd use on Earth?

There is obviously going to be considerations due to the variables involved (how much more gravity and how much thinner an atmosphere) but there are also other factors such as humidity, temperature, altitude, etc.

When firing, the distance is important because, with higher gravity, the bullet will drop faster and, with thinner atmosphere, the bullet will travel faster and further. This is why you see in computer games, like Sniper Elite, that the player needs to aim higher to account for gravity and aim ahead of a moving target to account for the time and distance to reach the target.

So to answer your final question, what should happen is that the bullet drops quicker but will likely travel further/faster as it will slow down at a slower rate than in a thicker atmosphere due to less friction. But it depends on how much extra gravity and how thin the atmosphere is.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity doesn't affect the speed of the bullet unless it has a vertical component. What it does do is mess with the trajectory and if course the mechanism of the firearm itself (especially making sure that it feeds reliably).

Atmospheric density and sound speed, however, have significant affects on bullets.

1. Low air density means that small rounds reach their target with more of their energy left and less lost due to drag.
2. Sound speed directly affects bullet aerodynamics.
3. Spin-stabilization is more effective if there is less drag. I would expect longer thinner projectiles to be viable which would further cut down on drag.
4. Bullet drop would increase from gravity, but bullets would reach their target sooner since there is lower drag.
5. If the speed of sound is higher, for example because of a hydrogen or helium atmosphere, the projectile may be subsonic and therefore also much quieter, making silenced high-powered rifles viable.
6. I would expect that light fast rounds would benefit from this change. Expect to see small bullets with high muzzle velocity to reduce bullet drop, since they don't lose much energy at long range, which is the main downside of light fast rounds on Earth.

Answer (score -3):

The vector of the bullet trajectory would follow the spacetime gravitational structure falling on the planet surface sooner that in a lighter gravity.
The bullet velocity will not be modified by friction if the atmospheric density is not higher than the initial comparative one.
Now increased gravity augment the weight of the bullet that may decrease the bullet velocity ( On a second thought)The bullet acceleration would be diminished.
My opinion: it would be slower and a shorter trajectory.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. The weight of the bullet doesn't influence its velocity. Only its mass does.